# I want to learn iphone development programming

Tags: ios

I want to learn iphone programming.How can I learn please suggest some links or some books that I can start iphone programming.

Comment: I'd suggest http://www.google.com as a good place to start

Comment: Apple has like a thousand hours of video you can watch online..

Comment: @MikeChristensen thousands of video is not a start point, a start point is one video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an apple document "My First iphone Application". There are some of that turorials written by other people.

This starts with learning Objective-C.
 In page http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/ there is on the left side the topic "Getting started". Start there.

How you learn also depeneds on your software developper experience.

I learned it, by reading some hours (about 3) , then coding 2-3 hours, and reading again what I didnt understand. And so on.

You must find yourself the right balance between reading theory and coding.

You need an intel mac for developping: e.g mac mini, if you want to try out your programms on the iphone you need 99$ per year to get a Apple SW developper license.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/) is the best place to start off with.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I started by watching the iTunes U lectures on iPhone development. Awesome stuff!